# Why are electromagnetic field modes considered a continuum of states (e.g. in the Fermi Golden Rule calculation)?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, density-of-states, fermis-golden-rule

When we consider a state transition e.g. from 2p to 1s in the hydrogen atom, the energy gets emitted in the form of a photon.

As an assumption underlying the Golden Rule application, we expect an infinite number of possible final states to be available. What is the degree of freedom that makes the number of final states so large/infinite?

Clearly, in terms of the frequency/energy of the photon, we don't have any degrees of freedom (since the energy is given as 2p-1s). The photon must have the energy corresponding to the state transition. Is it that each of infinitely many possible emission angles is considered a different state, therefore making the number of possible final states infinite?